# How to access deep JSON element in Java

Tags: java, json, google-distancematrix-api

i have the following JSON response:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Berlin, Deutschland" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Mannheim, Deutschland" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "624 km",
                  "value" : 624195
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 Stunden, 53 Minuten",
                  "value" : 21156
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

MY question is: How do I access the "text" Element in the "distance" section?

I have the following right now:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
JSONArray rows= null;
rows= object.getJSONArray("rows");
```

Comment: which json parser are you using? Apache? Android? Simple?

Answer (score 2):

You either have to continue parsing the JSONArray, e.g.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    JSONArray elements = rows.getJSONArray(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {   
        JSONObject current = elements.getJSONObject(j);
        String curText = current.getJSONObject("distance").getJSONObject("text");
    }    
}
```

Or you can represent your Json in a POJO and deserialize it using Jackson's ObjectMapper for example.

Comment: I get the error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"elements":[{"distance":{"text":"624 km","value":624195},"duration":{"text":"5 hours 53 mins","value":21156},"status":"OK"}]} at 0 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: In your example you portrayed elements as an array. The exception tells you it's a JSONObject. Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but you can try something like that

```
JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjInput.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject tmp = jsonObjInput.getJSONObject(i);
       }
```

Clément